# stream can't cast char to int

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

my code is throwing an error below, not sure why that's happening

[image]

```
int input = 351;
String inputString = Integer.toString(input);
System.out.println("input:- " + inputString);
char[] inputChar = inputString.toCharArray();
List data = Arrays.asList(inputChar);

data.stream().map((entry)-> ((int)entry-48)).forEach((entry)->{
  System.out.println(entry);
});
```

changed the above code to

```
String val = inputString.chars().map((entry)-> ((int)entry-48)).sorted().reduce("",(initial,entry)->entry+initial);
```

I am seeing an error at the reduce method level

[image]

Comment: Note that `inputString.chars()` will give you an `IntStream` of the `char` values (upcast to int).

Comment: Try, _Character[] inputChar = (Character[]) inputString.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char) (x - 48)).toArray()_

Comment: First step to a solution is to avoid the raw type `List` and consider which element type you expected. Once you write for example `List<char>`, `List<Character>` or `List<char[]>` and see whether you get any new error message, the situation will already be clearer to you. Or just let your IntelliJ suggest the type of `data` for you.

Comment: The problem with the original code is that `List` is a `List<char[]>`, not a `List<Character>`.

Comment: The problem with the new code is that `inputString.chars()` is an `IntStream`, so `reduce` expects `int` as the first argument parameter, but you have a `String` as the first input.  If you convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<String>` using `mapToObj` you get the result you're looking for (`"531"`): `inputString.chars().map(entry -> entry - 48).sorted().mapToObj(String::valueOf).reduce("", (initial, entry) -> entry + initial);`